How do I reset the GSAP animation once the element is scrolled out of viewport?
I have 3 elements in a div and I rigged them to slide in with a 1 second delay with ScrollTrigger, but my scrub is off.
The animation is triggered accordingly when I scroll the element into view. However, I want the animation to reset once I scroll out and to start again if I reach the ScrollTrigger trigger
aboutTags.forEach((aboutTag, index) => {
  gsap.set(aboutTag, {
    xPercent: -20,
    opacity: 0
  });

  gsap.to(aboutTag, {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: about,
      start: 'top 50%',
    },
    delay: index * 1,
    xPercent: 0,
    opacity: 1
  })
})


You should use the onEnter and onLeave callbacks, for that they were created, among other things. You should also set the toggleActions parameter to properly handle the animation state as the element enters and exits the viewport.
https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/?page=1#onEnter
https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/?page=1#onLeave
https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/?page=1#toggleActions
const aboutTags = document.querySelectorAll('.about');

  aboutTags.forEach((aboutTag, index) => {
    gsap.set(aboutTag, {
      xPercent: -20,
      opacity: 0
    });

    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: aboutTag,
      start: 'top 80%',
      onEnter: () => animateIn(aboutTag, index),
      onLeave: () => resetAnimation(aboutTag),
      onEnterBack: () => animateIn(aboutTag, index),
      onLeaveBack: () => resetAnimation(aboutTag),
      toggleActions: 'play none none none'
    });
  });

  function animateIn(element, index) {
    gsap.to(element, {
      xPercent: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      delay: index * 1,
      duration: 1
    });
  }

  function resetAnimation(element) {
    gsap.to(element, {
      xPercent: -20,
      opacity: 0,
      duration: 1
    });
  }

https://codepen.io/Lucas_Mas/full/XWwVryO
